# C:\TempPath directory is growing too large. What is it and how do I stop it?

Tags: 2013, logging, server

I've been searching for an answer the past few weeks but I can't figure out where these files are coming from.  On the server that hosts our SP sites and services, there is a directory called C:\TempPath.  When I first stumbled upon this, it had over 6m+ files in it.  After removing the directory, it quickly reappeared and has grown to over 16k+ files now.  Every single file is a GUID (i.e. "95007211-da72-4a64-b7a6-bcca3ae8adc5") without a file extension.  There is a single file in this directory called startTime.txt which simply contains a time stamp of when the directory was recreated.

Every time I add, update, or delete a document in SharePoint, a new file appears in this directory with these details.

**Here is what the files all look like:**

`<FILETAG>SPAudit0</FILETAG>
<OPT>MetaData Updated</OPT>
<NAME>MyFile.pdf</NAME>
<LOCATION>https://FQDN.com/MySiteName/Documents/MyFilePath/MyFile.pdf</LOCATION>
<PERMNAME>null</PERMNAME>
<UNAME>null</UNAME>
<GNAME>null</GNAME>
<WHO>John Doe</WHO>
<WHEN>2019/5/16 09:05:18</WHEN>
<SNAME>MySiteName</SNAME>
<OBJTYPE>Document</OBJTYPE>
<SURL>https://FQDN.com/MySiteName</SURL>
<DETAILS>[Comments] MetaData Updated 
<SLASH_R>
<SLASH_N> From: **Prior Value**
<SLASH_R>
<SLASH_N> To: **New Value**
</DETAILS>
<AURL>null</AURL>`

Can anybody identify what this is?  I've checked the gatherer and diagnostic service file paths (both of which are stored on a secondary drive (E:)), I've searched the registry for this file path, and I've gone through every piece of configuration I know of.  My best guess is that this is something not well known or well hidden from documentation.

Hopefully the file contents will look familiar to someone else.

Comment: C:\TempPath is not a default Temp location for windows, so, this looks like a custom functionality. I would suggest to check the custom functionalities in your code, like event listeners etc. to see if there is any reference.

Comment: @UBK The files are owned by IUSR (IIS) and the only thing running is SharePoint.  It's definitely not a default path but I can't find any references to it within configurations, registry, or IIS.

Comment: Please check if you can find 'Audit settings' in your site collection administration page. Also, if there is any 'Audit' related feature in your Farm/ Site collection.